# Warning: mysqli::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement when assigning variables dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently looking at ways to use an API to connect and manage queries securely (SQL injection  mitigation), while trying to follow DRY guidelines. I use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections, but I am running into warnings when running the function that is called when an HTTP GET request is received:

> Warning: mysqli::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement...

An then my query fails with:

> Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now Errno 2014

A simple google search provides me with this answer:

> If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.

The warnings and error message only happens when there is more than one argument in the array.
My mySQL query function is as follows:

```
    //set properties to values given by constructor params, 
    //open mysqli connection, etc..

    public function query_db_stmt($sql, $param)
    {

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($param); ++$i)
        {
            $stmt->bind_param(($param[0][$i - 1]), $param[$i]);  
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        $stmt->close();
        return $result;
    } // do other stuff here, like close the sql connection in __destruct()...
```

And then I create the object and then invoke the query function like so:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ? FROM user WHERE id=?;';
$result = $mysql_db->query_db_stmt($sql, array('si', '*', $this->args[0]));
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, as I get these warnings, and a Err number 2014, but I cannot figure out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

### EDIT:

I now understand that I cannot use the column or table name as an prepared statement, but I still have a similar problem when using this code except with a HTTP PUT request:

```
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $put_vars);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO user (username, password, email, birth, sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);';
    $mysql_db->query_db_stmt($sql, array('sssss', $put_vars['username'], password_hash($put_vars['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT), 
      $put_vars['email'], $put_vars['birth'], $put_vars['sex']));
```

Using curl, I run curl -X PUT http://localhost/r.php -d username=foo -d password=boo -d email=test@gmail.com -d birthday=2015-08-13 -d sex=m

And I get the same error 5 times:

> Warning: mysqli::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement...

As before, But no DB Query failed error. Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to bind the table name in PDO. Table and Column name cannot be replaced in PDO.

Comment: As I interpret your answer, you are saying I cannot replace treble and column names when using prepared statements, is that correct? At another point, I query [code]$sql = 'INSERT INTO user (username, password, email) VALUES(?, ?, ?);' [/code] (I believe that is correct, but I can't check syntax as I am on my phone), and the same thing happens.

Comment: that is correct and should not give `number of params don't match` error. If there is some other error edit the question so i can help better :)

Comment: have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php You need to pass `n` parameter and not an array with n elements

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the column name in a `?` and prepare the statement. Instead just take the values of the statement as params and bind the variables to them. 
So, the `$sql` should be-

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?';
```

Then bind the variables accordingly.

Also, don't use `SELECT *` in your queries, always specify the column names you want output from.

Comment: Understood, but I would still like to use the query func with mutiple parameters.

Comment: You can use multiple parameters for the queries. Just don't use the column names as a `?`.